# Openerp NotImplementedError: Iteration is not allowed on browse_record(stock.move, 159275)

Tags: python, function, iteration, odoo, wizard

I'm browsing for records, then I would like to perform specific code if browsing return results.

Here is my code :

```
 def create_update_date(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        _log.info ('this is method to create a MO')
        _log.info (context)
        picking_obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking')
        move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')
        for stock in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            for  wiz in picking_obj.browse(cr, uid, stock.stock_id.id, context=None):
                date_pick = stock.date
                for wizs in wiz.move_lines:
                    move_obj.write(cr,uid,wizs,{'date_expected':date_pick})
```

But it does not work, when evaluating the if condition, an exception is raised :

```
NotImplementedError: Iteration is not allowed on browse_record(stock.move, 159275)
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve, add this before your `for` loop:

```
if not isinstance(ids, list):
    ids = [ids]
```

The catch is that `ids` can be wither a list of ids or a numeric id.

In the latter case, `browse` returns a single record, non iterable, instead of an iterable collection of records. The solution is to make sure `ids` is a list.

Another possible cause for the problem is the last `write()` command: it the `wizs` is a Record, and the write operation expects an ID. You may try replacing it with:

```
move_obj.write(cr, uid, wizs.id, {'date_expected':date_pick})
```

Comment: i have done write script on my module. 
but still same error code.`NotImplementedError: Iteration is not allowed on browse_record(stock.move, 159275)`can u help me, please?